# Navbar layout shifting in flexbox using tailwind css

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

on hover bold, text is shifting layout. I am using tailwind css. this is my code

https://play.tailwindcss.com/fAUieA44OB

I don't want to use position absolute or anything which disturbs responsiveness.

```
<div class="mx-12 flex items-center justify-around">
  <nav>
    <ul class="flex gap-8">
      <li>
        <a href="/" class="text-2xl font-normal hover:font-bold"> Shop </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/About" class="text-2xl font-normal hover:font-bold"> About us </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/Contact" class="text-2xl font-normal hover:font-bold"> Contact us </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code works on large screen and not small screen.
BTW on small screen we don't use hover effect.

```
<div class="mx-12 flex items-center justify-around">
  <nav  style="width:100%"> <!-- Changed this -->
    <ul class="flex text-center justify-center"> <!-- Changed this --> 
      <li style="width:33%">  <!-- Changed this -->
        <a href="/" class="text-2xl font-normal hover:font-bold"> Shop </a>
      </li>
      <li  style="width:33%">  <!-- Changed this -->
        <a href="/About" class="text-2xl font-normal hover:font-bold"> About us </a>
      </li>
      <li style="width:33%">  <!-- Changed this -->
        <a href="/Contact" class="text-2xl font-normal hover:font-bold"> Contact us </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

The idea is to make the width of containers (here, <li>) **independent** of the content (here, <a>).
If the width of containers depends on the width of content, then if the content becomes bold (thereby increasing its size), the width of container also increases. The container (<li>) affects the position of other containers (<li>) within their parent <ul> (flex). So there is layout shift.
If the width of containers (<li>) is independent of the content, then there is no layout shift.

Instead of `style="width:33%"`, another way could be to use `style="flex:1 1 33%"` on all <li>s.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Thanks

Comment: Thank You. This is really helpful. I am starting to code and love this community.

This is for large screens. I have another layout for small screen

Thanks Again.